# How can I change the value of the input index's of the function in the function?

Tags: c++, function, memory, indexing

How should I do it so that all the indexes of the input array of my function are converted to the character "?"
I know it should be done using the address of this array, but I have no idea
the function:

```
void something (char s1[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen (s1); i++) {
        cout<<i;
        s1[i] = '?';
    }
}
int main() {
    something ("The String!");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: add the code that calls the function

Comment: If it's giving you a segfault use a debugger to find out exactly why. You should also check `s1` for null and throw an exception if it is. That way you know if the rest of your code is passing what is expected.

Comment: You're not sending a  `char{}`. You're sending a string constant, which cannot be modified.

Comment: Othet than the use of `cout` I see nothing particularly C++ey about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you really want is to convert every charter of your input string to "?". The main issue with your code is that "The String!" is of type `char*` and is stored in code section of memory, so you cannot modify its characters. However you can define it as an array instead.

```
void something (char s1[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen (s1); i++) {
        cout<<i;
        s1[i] = '?';
    }
}
int main() {
    char input[] = "The String!";
    something (input);
    getch();
    return 0; // do not forget to return value from your function.
}
```

In general I'd recommend to do not use C-style strings, but C++-style `std::string` (you can pass it to your function by reference to omit copying).

Comment: Sorry, this answer is technically wrong. "The String!" is not of type `char*` but it is `const char[12]`.  In the function "something" the parameter "s1" decays to type "char *". And `const char[12]` cannot be converted to `char*` because of its "constness". Also, "code section of memory" is wrong. We do not know (and do not care), where it will be stored. And, in C++, you can omit `return 0` in main. Not any more necessary. As a side node, my C++ compiler does not compile function "getch", but maybe yours does. I would be happy, if you could update the answer. Then I will delete my comment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
`And const char[12] cannot be converted to char* because of its constness".`
I do not agree with this because in this case your code will not compile. Here the program can be compiled successfully.
Regarding `getch`, this is non standard function, it’s available on ms-dos platforms.
Regarding returning from main, you are right you can omit it, and most of the time compiler will not complain (depends on compiler settings), but in general as a good practice it’s better to have it.

Comment: I fail to understand you. The code of the OP does not compile! I get 3 errors and 2 messages stating exactly what I was telling you. Are you using a C++ compiler with C++enabled? Did you maybe forget to enable compiler warnings. And, `getch`  is not part of the C++ ISO standard. Please check the standard. Also your statement regarding the `return` in main is wrong. It is not needed, independent from compiler settings. Please see here:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function, topic 4)  I am really wondering with what confidence your are making these wrong statements . . .

Comment: “Code does not compile” and “compilation warnings” are different things. Your compiler can warn you but still compile the code. The code from question is compilable. Mb it is not compilable on your side, check if your compiler is setup to treat warnings as errors. Here we do not know which compiler was used and what settings it had. But my main point is that it is compilable. Regarding `getch`, I think you missed my comment. I did not say it is a part of standard.